# Is there a way to create a Custom Cloud Foundry Buildpack to run Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I am working on a project which requires me to update the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in registry with the path of properties file in a Cloud Foundry Windows container?

So far I have tried to update the HKLM using a dotNet application but that is failing since there is no admin privilege for the application running in the container.

I am trying to think of an alternate solution wherein I can update the HKLM registry key using PowerShell script through a custom buildpack. So, is there a way to create a customer Cloud Foundry Buildpack to run the Powershell script?

Comment: Try even opening the docs.  They have a section dedicated to custom buildpacks.

Comment: First, buildpacks do not have any additional permissions beyond those of your application. They both run as a non-Administrator user. If the problem is that you require admin permissions, then a buildpack isn't going to be any help. It will hit the same limitation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create a Custom Cloud Foundry Buildpack to run Powershell script?

Yes. By default, the buildpack is going to run batch scripts, but you can very easily call Powershell from there. Take a look at the HWC buildpack, which is doing just that.

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted %~dp0\detect.ps1 %1
```

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/hwc-buildpack/tree/master/bin